# webstorm не видит поля аргументов передаваемые импортируемым модулям

Tags: webstorm

на втором скрине в файле App.jsx webstorm подчеркивает желтым поле cash у аргумента state и предлагает создать его. но оно есть - в первом скрине в файле index.js видно что поле сash у state есть оно передается в reducer с помощью которого передается в store, содержимое которого с помощью компонента  может использовать этот самый хук useDispatch().

у меня компонент отлично работает, вот [тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dzzeir85i3c&list=PL6DxKON1uLOHsBCJ_vVuvRsW84VnqmPp6&index=2) у чувака webstorm все отлично видит, а у меня нет, но почему? это какойто плагин? или какаято опция?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Нет таких настроек; проголосуйте, пожалуйста, за [WEB-50731](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-50731), чтобы получать уведомления об обновлении статуса этого запроса. К сожалению, для его исправления потребуется обеспечить специальную поддержку Redux, в частности, распознавание хука `useSelector()`,  поскольку inferred тип параметра здесь — `DefaultRootState`, и ваши поля не определены для этого типа и не могут быть найдены с помощью статического анализа кода.

В качестве обходного пути вы можете явно указать тип параметра с помощью JSDoc, например:

```
const cash = useSelector(/** import('./store').defaultState */ state => state.cash)
```

Comment: проголосовал, но почему здесь https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLeK7vIEi5I&list=PL6DxKON1uLOHsBCJ_vVuvRsW84VnqmPp6&index=5 у человека все определяется? может быть всетаки есть какойто плагин?

Comment: нет. скорее всего, просто инспекции выключены